# como puedo sumar todos los valores iguales en Javascript

Tags: javascript, arraylist, javascript-objeto

> necesito Transformar este objeto a el que sigue en Javascript

```
//Original
[
  { word: 'form', value: 4 },
  { word: 'form', value: 4 },
  { word: 'default', value: 4 },
  { word: 'default', value: 30 },
  { word: 'default', value: 31 },
  { word: '[None]', value: 11 },
  { word: '2.- Imagen_1', value: 4 },
  { word: '2.- Imagen_1', value: 3 },
  { word: '2.- Andres_1', value: 22 },
  { word: '1.- Guardar información_0', value: 4 },
  { word: '1.- Guardar información_0', value: 4 }
]

//Transformado

[
  { word: 'form', value: 8},
  { word: 'default', value: 65 },
  { word: '[None]', value: 11 },
  { word: '2.- Andres_1', value: 22 },
  { word: '1.- Guardar información_0', value: 8 }
]
```

> eh intentado de varias maneras, como un for que que suma el valor siguente con el anterior, pero solo suma 2 iguales y al querer volver a usar el ciclo manda que el valor es indefinido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    { word: 'form', value: 4 },
    { word: 'form', value: 4 },
    { word: 'default', value: 4 },
    { word: 'default', value: 30 },
    { word: 'default', value: 31 },
    { word: '[None]', value: 11 },
    { word: '2.- Imagen_1', value: 4 },
    { word: '2.- Imagen_1', value: 3 },
    { word: '2.- Andres_1', value: 22 },
    { word: '1.- Guardar información_0', value: 4 },
    { word: '1.- Guardar información_0', value: 4 }
]

const claves = []

//Agregamos todas las claves al arreglo sin repetición
data.forEach(item => {
    if (!claves.includes(item.word)){
        claves.push(item.word)
    }
})

//Por cada clave...
const res = claves.map(clave => ({
    word: clave,
    value: (
        data.filter(item => item.word === clave) //Obtenemos todos los elementos con esa propiedad word
        .reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.value, 0) //Obtenemos la suma de todos sus values
    )
}))

console.log(res)
```