# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores repetidos de un objeto dentro de un array? en javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Quiera saber cómo realizar esta suma, en el cual se muestra un arreglo de objetos repetidos;

```
[ { mango: 2 }, { mango: 2 }, { mango: 3 }, { pera: 10 } ]
```

para que el resultado sea

```
[ mango: 7, pera: 10 ]
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [como puedo sumar todos los valores iguales en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/530807/como-puedo-sumar-todos-los-valores-iguales-en-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo así:

```js
let mercado = [
  {
    fruta: "mango",
    cantidad: 1,
  },
  {
    fruta: "mango",
    cantidad: 2,
  },
  {
    fruta: "pera",
    cantidad: 4,
  },
  {
    fruta: "mango",
    cantidad: 2,
  },
];

const duplicado = mercado.reduce((acumulador, valorActual) => {
  // Guardamos en una variable los objetos del arreglo que tienen el valor repetido de la clave "fruta".
  const siExiste = acumulador.find(
    elemento => elemento.fruta === valorActual.fruta
  );

  // Si hay objetos repetidos...
  if (siExiste) {
    // Mapeamos al valor inicial "acumulador" de los objetos repetidos.
    return acumulador.map(elemento => {
      // Verificamos si coincide la clave "fruta" de lo mapeado con el objeto devuelto por el reduce
      if (elemento.fruta === valorActual.fruta) {
        // Retornará la clave "cantidad" sumando sus valores con las demás repetidas.
        return {
          ...elemento,
          cantidad: elemento.cantidad + valorActual.cantidad,
        };
      }
      return elemento;
    });
  }
  // Retornamos todo el resultado, que se almacenará en un nuevo array de objetos.
  return [...acumulador, valorActual];
}, []);

console.log(duplicado);
```

Comment: ¡¡Gracias por la ayuda!! es una forma distinta a la que buscaba, pero el resultado es increíble

Answer (score 0):

Usando [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let frutas = [{ mango: 2 }, { mango: 2 }, { mango: 3 }, { pera: 10 }];

//acc es el acumulador, es un array que empieza vacio y se llena en cada interación
//item es el elemento en la iteracion, similar al foreach
var resultado = frutas.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let key = Object.keys(item);

    if (!acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = item[key];
    }
    else {
        acc[key] = acc[key] + item[key];
    }

    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(resultado["mango"])
console.log(resultado["pera"])
console.log(resultado) //NO funciona!!
```

Extrañamente console.log(resultado)  no da resultado, esto fue lo que más me sorprendió, al parecer hay un error en el snippet del stackoverflow, porque al probarlo en el navegador funciona como debe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda!! estaba en duda en como poder conseguir el resultado, me sirvió tu respuesta

Comment: Fantástico!!!, recuerda darle el visto a la respuesta

Comment: Por si acaso, la última línea imprime un arreglo vacío porque la manera en que funciona el código es definiendo nuevos miembros en el objeto.