# ¿Cómo se podría encontrar los duplicados dentro de un array de string y sumar los valores en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo este dato como entrada

```
const animales = ["gatos:3","gatos:2","perros:4","conejos:2","perros:2"]
```

Para que el resultado sea

```
resultado = ["gatos:5","perros:6","conejos:2"]
```

Tengo resuelto esta parte pero no logro entender lo demás

```
const animales = ["gatos:3","gatos:2","perros:4","conejos:2","perros:2"]
const arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < animales.length; i++) {
    const e = animales[i];
    const info = {};
    info[e.split(':')[0]] = Number(e.split(':')[1]);
    arr.push(info);
}
const valor = {};
const sum = 0;
arr.forEach( e => {
    for(const key in e) {
        if (!valor[key]) {
            valor[key] = sum + e[key];
        }
    }
})
console.log(valor);
```

Comment: Mira esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/559209/301324

Comment: Has intentado algo? danos ejemplos de algo que hayas hecho

Comment: Tengo hasta esa parte resuelta pero no entiendo lo demás

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurrió una forma en la que aprovechas que Javascript es un lenguaje basado en prototipos.

El resultado es un objeto pero puedes convertirlo fácilmente en un arreglo si necesitas.

Quizá no conozcas el operador [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). En pocas palabras, si el operando izquierdo es `null` o `undefined`  devuelve el operando derecho. Sino, devuelve el operando izquierdo.

```js
animales = ["gatos:3","gatos:2","perros:4","conejos:2","perros:2","gatos:5","conejos:1","perros:8"]
resultado = {}

for (animal of animales){
    split = animal.split(":")
    resultado[split[0]] = (resultado[split[0]] ?? 0) + parseInt(split[1])
}

// Resultado es un objeto 
console.log(resultado)

// Puedes mapear el objeto en un arreglo
resultado = Object.entries(resultado).map(par => par[0] + ":" + par[1])

console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: muy buena tu solucion viendo la mia me doy cuenta que tengo que aprender mas jaja

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego no estaba mal. No te avergüences, quizá al autor de la pregunta la gustaba más tu solución. Yo publiqué la mía porque tiene varias diferencias del tuyo, sino no lo hubiera hecho.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, la verdad la dos soluciones me sirvieron bastante para seguir practicando y ver distintas formas de realizarlo

Answer (score 0):

```
var animales = ["gatos:3","gatos:2","perros:4","conejos:2","perros:2","gatos:5","conejos:1","perros:8"]
const resultado = [];

function countAnimals () {
  for(let i=0;i<animales.length;i++){ // para cada elemento del array
    let animal = animales[i].split(":")[0] // guardamos temporalmente el nombre de 1 animal
    let acum = 0; // declaramos un acumulador
    for(let h=0;h<animales.length;h++){ 
      if(animales[h].startsWith(animal))  acum += parseInt(animales[h].split(":")[1]) // si es el mismo animal suma su cantidad al acumulador
    }
  resultado.push(`${animal}:${acum}`) // se agrega al array "resultado" la concatenacion del animal evaluado y del acumulador, y se repite el proceso con los demas animales
  }
}

countAnimals() 
const norepeats = [...new Set(resultado)] // esta es una forma de eliminar los duplicados en un array usando Set
console.log(norepeats) // se imprime el resultado
```